# What is the maximum voltage of a coin cell battery?

Tags: batteries, coin-cell

The nominal voltage seems to be 3V for a coin cell battery (e.g. motherboard battery), but what the maximum of a fully charged battery fresh out of a package from the factory?  What is the theoretical max?

Comment: Have you consulted the datasheet?

Comment: I don't have a practical datasheet.  This came from a corner store.  Per this, it seems less than 3.5, but hard to tell with greater resolution from that plot.  https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/maxell_cr2032_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Theoretical max or max available to puchase in store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the [chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)).
For non-rechargable lithium manganese dioxide batteries that would be theoretically 3.4V.

However, you can also buy rechargable lithium cobalt oxide button cell batteries, which is theoretically 4.2V, just like any other lithium-ion battery.